# The XPath @root-node-position attribute info

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

I couldn't find the `@root-node-position` XPath attribute/selector info. Would you give me a link of where i can read about it? Is it XPath 2.0?
The code (not mine) is `../preceding-sibling::div[1]/div[@root-node-position]/div` applied to this HTML:

```
<div class="left">
      <div class='prod2'>
         <div class='name'>Dell Latitude D610-1.73 Laptop Wireless Computer
         </div>2 GHz Intel Pentium M, 1 GB DDR2 SDRAM, 40 GB 
      </div>
      <div class='prod1'>
         <div class='name'>Samsung Chromebook (Wi-Fi, 11.6-Inch)
         </div>1.7 GHz, 2 GB DDR3 SDRAM, 16 GB
      </div>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <div class='price2'>$239.95</div>
  <div class='price1 best'>$249.00</div>
</div>
```

Firstly i fetch a price text under class='right' with this query : `//DIV[contains(@class,'best')]` and then i apply the above mentioned XPath with @root-node-attribute under class='left' to retrieve the rest of the record info.

Comment: Please share some code where you try to find the root node's attribute info.

Comment: In the provided XML fragment there is no `root-node-position` attribute anywhere. Please, edit the question and provide the right source XML document.

Comment: @root-node-position is an XPath attribute/selector, not of XML code (ex. div[1]: 1 - attribute/selector is not in XML as well). This is the difference, therefore it's not present in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @root-node-position is a non-standard XPath attribute that is only
supported by Visual Web Ripper.

You can read more about non-standard XPath methods, attributes and
axis supported by Visual Web Ripper [here](http://manual.visualwebripper.com/default.aspx?manual_id=345), only for registered users.

Answer (score 1):

In C# this approach can be handy:

```
XmlDocument docSourceFile = new XmlDocument();
docSourceFile.Load("XML file path goes here");
XmlNode nodRoot = docSourceFile.DocumentElement;
string strAttributeValue = nodRoot .Attributes ["Write Attribute Name Here"].Value;
```

Generally, in XPath we use like below to get value of attributes of RootNode:

```
/RootNodeName/@AttributeName
```

Good Luck.